# Word wrap in Gvim

Tags: vim, word-wrap

How do I make Gvim word wrap in such a way that doesn't break words in the middle?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Looks like there is a solution online after all.

```
:set formatoptions=l
:set lbr
```

Link: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Word_wrap_without_line_breaks

Comment: For anyone else having problems figuring out why linebreak/lbr won't work, double check that you haven't turned list on (i.e. :set nolist); it disables linebreak. (D'oh!  Pulled out some hair while searching the docs because of that.)

Comment: what about for printing?  if I print, it still breaks words in the middle.

Answer (score 19):

You can

```
:set nowrap
```

to just let huge lines scroll of the edge of your screen. But tw is probably the better way to go.

Comment: :set wrap will then enable wrapping :-p

Comment: for really wide files in `gvim` I combine this with `:set guioptions+=b` (enables horizontal scrollbar)

Comment: The question is *"How do I **make Gvim word wrap** in such a way ..."* ... wtf does this have 10 upvotes?

Comment: It doesn't answer the question but it was my Google top result for my question "how do I disable word wrap in gvim" so I used this answer.

Answer (score 7):

you can

```
:set wrap linebreak nolist
```

Answer (score 6):

```
:set tw=78
```

sets the text width to 78 characters.  You can use "[movement]gq" to re-wrap some text.

Comment: This is not exactly what I had in mind. If I resize the window it still breaks the words. I want the same behavior you would expect in Windows text editors.

Comment: For the record, tw=78 (short for "textwidth") causes vi to actually add newlines as you type.  The newlines become part of the file.  I use this a lot when I want vi to format for me as I type.  To format already-entered text, use gq} or !}fmt or !}fold

Comment: This is called *hard-wrapping*, the question is vague but reading the comments it is implied the author is looking about *soft-wrapping*.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following settings to wrap long lines for things like markdown files.

```
:set wrap
:set linebreak
:set nolist  " list disables linebreak
:set textwidth=0
:set wrapmargin=0
```

Source: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Word_wrap_without_line_breaks

Answer (score -1):

You can also use wrapmargin, which the manual defines as:

```
Number of characters from the right window border where wrapping
starts.  When typing text beyond this limit, an <EOL> will be inserted
and inserting continues on the next line.
```

Comment: I'm confused by this option: I don't want my current terminal width to determine how the file is saved.