# Word Wrap in Vim (preserving indentation)

Tags: vim, word-wrap

I was just looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744159/word-wrap-in-gvim) which describes how to wrap entire words in vim.  The accepted solution was this:

```
:set formatoptions=l
:set lbr
```

Which takes this text (tabs are shown as \t):

```
 *Inside of window                        *Outside of window
|---------------------------------------|    
|\t\tthis is a like of text that will wr|ap here                            
|\t\tcan you see the wrap               |
|                                       |
|---------------------------------------|
```

This accomplishes a behavior like this (tabs are shown as \t):

```
 *Inside of window                        *Outside of window
|---------------------------------------|    
|\t\tthis is a like of text that will   |
|wrap here                              |
|\t\tcan you see the wrap               |
|                                       |
|---------------------------------------|
```

I would however like to redefine this function.  I would like the wrapped line to have the same number of tabs in front of it that the line above has plus one.  Ie:

```
 *Inside of window                        *Outside of window
|---------------------------------------|    
|\t\tthis is a like of text that will   |
|\t\t\twrap here                        |
|\t\tcan you see the wrap               |
|                                       |
|---------------------------------------|
```

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for the effort taken to make the question as clear as possible.

Comment: Do you want the text to soft-wrap at the edge of the window, or hard-wrap when the line reaches a certain length? I think you want hard-wrapping (where a newline is inserted into your text after the word "will"), but it's difficult to tell from your examples.

Comment: @Bill, I am mostly interested in softwrapping but a hardwrapping solution would also be acceptable.

Comment: The functionality you want isn't currently built in to Vim. There's a patch that comes close, however: http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/web/vim-patches (it's #15, "Correctly indent wrapped lines").

Comment: Related: VimCasts had a nice episode on using external unix utilities to handle this problem: http://vimcasts.org/e/18/

Comment: @BillOdom your link is broken

Comment: @DamienWilson I could be mistaken but I think the OP is asking about word wrap, not word formatting. If I use par on, for example, my php code, it will break my long functions in two.

Comment: Check out the answers to this SO questions for info on a certain Vim `breakindent` patch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759577/how-do-i-make-text-wrapping-match-current-indentation-level-in-vim

Comment: possible duplicate of [Smart Wrap in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204149/smart-wrap-in-vim)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204149/smart-wrap-in-vim?rq=1

Comment: From [superuser](http://superuser.com/a/73190/48920): [Versions of vim >= 7.4.354 now include this feature](https://retracile.net/blog/2014/07/18/18.00).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [breakindent patch](https://retracile.net/wiki/VimBreakIndent) has what you're looking for. I successfully applied it using instructions found in this thread:

[Patch Vim with the breakindent patch on OS X with Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323095/patch-vim-on-mac-with-homebrew)

Specifically, echristopherson's Homebrew formula.

I know this thread is old but it's popular on google and I came across it multiple times when trying to find a solution.

EDIT: This patch is now included with vim as patch 7.4.338. See: https://retracile.net/blog/2014/07/18/18.00

On Yosemite (Mac OS X), I used snowbound's command with hombrew:

```
brew install macvim --with-features=huge --override-system-vim --HEAD
```

Comment: the patch doesn't seem to work with the latest macvim on homebrew?  @Exit42 how did you get it to work?

Comment: nvm. I compiled macvim with homebrew bleeding edge `brew install macvim --with-features=huge --override-system-vim --HEAD`

Comment: See my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828174/word-wrap-in-vim-preserving-indentation/26578161#26578161

No need for a patch in newer versions of vim.

Answer (score 38):

This did not work when the question was originally asked, but as of June 25, 2014, this will work. (Assuming you update your vim to a version newer than that date)

Add to your .vimrc:

```
" Indents word-wrapped lines as much as the 'parent' line
set breakindent
" Ensures word-wrap does not split words
set formatoptions=l
set lbr
```

And that's it!

--

Some people (myself included) share a single .vimrc across multiple computers.  In that case, it's important to have this line be robust (to avoid annoying error messages). This is a little better:

```
if has("patch-7.4.354")
    " Indents word-wrapped lines as much as the 'parent' line
    set breakindent
    " Ensures word-wrap does not split words
    set formatoptions=l
    set lbr
endif
```

This way, if you're on an earlier version of vim, you don't get an error message.

Comment: Interestingly, this works on my cygwin's 7.4 vim but not in my unbuntu's 7.4 vim.  I'm guessing it needs to get a little more widespread, but will see universal adoption soon.

Comment: Works in Vim 7.4 @ ArchLinux.

Comment: You can use this test instead: `if has("patch-7.4.354")`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question regarding OP's remark: *the same number of tabs (...)* **plus one**. It is by the way very important in my opinion too, you may often want to keep additional indentation and optically shift wrapped segments to the right (tightly arranged listings, notes, etc.);

Answer (score 9):

The best you're going to get is the `showbreak` option which will put a fixed string in front of each wrapped line (I use `set showbreak=...`).

Comment: @AlexanderBird According to [`:help 'showbreak'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27showbreak%27), no, you can’t – `showbreak` is only a string.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the answer that says 'showbreak' is the best option.  Showbreak does not typically allow you to put nonprinting characters (e.g., spaces or tabs) into the showbreak string, so as typically used it will just give you an indicator along left margin, i.e., no real indent.  This isn't great, since main goal of OP, I think, is to give wrapped lines an indent keep them from cluttering left margin area and looking like lines of their own.

So one way to add an (ugly) indent using showbreak is to just use a lot of characters, .e.g, ":set showbreak=>--------------->".  This results in something that looks like this:

```
 *Inside of window                        *Outside of window
|---------------------------------------|    
|\t\tthis is a like of text that will   |
|>--------------->wrap here             |
|\t\tcan you see the wrap               |
|                                       |
|---------------------------------------|
```

A better alternative might be to make use of nonbreaking space characters (assuming your instance of Vim is unicode enabled), each of which can be entered into the showbreak string using the key sequence of ctrl-v,160.  That way you can enter a showbreak string that is blank at the left side and appear to be a true indent.  E.g., ":set showbreak=. . . . . . . . . . >>" where each '.' in the command is actually a nonbreaking space character entered by pressing ctrl-V,160.  That way you end up with a wrap that is nicely indented, like this:

```
 *Inside of window                        *Outside of window
|---------------------------------------|    
|\t\tthis is a like of text that will   |
|            >>wrap here                |
|\t\tcan you see the wrap               |
|                                       |
|---------------------------------------|
```

You still don't have any ability to vary the level of indent according to indent of previous line, but at least you get clean indent of wrapped lines without lots of visual clutter along left margin of window.  There could still be confusion if indent of a wrapped line is less than that of the beginning of an actual line, but this could perhaps be avoided by making the showbreak "indent" quite large (i.e., greater than any indent commonly found in your code) but still small enough that it provides enough space for legible wrapping of the text.  For many uses I think a showbreak indent of 40 or 50 spaces would do this pretty well.

Comment: You can put spaces in showbreak by escaping them: `:set showbreak=\ \ \ \ `. Still doesn't work for tabs, however.

Comment: Being stuck on an old vim version on one of the computers I must use, the best solution I found, visually, is similar to yours: `set showbreak=\\__\ \ \ \ `. It is not very satisfying, but it gives a good visual clue.