# Word Wrap in Vim (preserving indentation) in Latex document

Tags: vim, word-wrap, tex

I was just looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828174/word-wrap-in-vim-preserving-indentation) post which describes how to wrap entire words in vim. I am looking for a way to key the indentation, or in my case, the lack of it.

I usually select a couple lines with `V` and press `gq` to reformat it and re-wrap the lines.

Let say, I have the following document

```
 *Inside of window                        *Outside of window
|---------------------------------------|    
|This is a bla like of text that will wr|ap here                            
|can you see the wrap                   |
|                                       |
|---------------------------------------|
```

The result will be:

```
 *Inside of window                        *Outside of window
|---------------------------------------|    
|This is a bla like of text that will   |                            
|wrap here can you see the wrap         |
|                                       |
|---------------------------------------|
```

So far so good.

Now Let say, I have the following document with some latex tags

```
 *Inside of window                        *Outside of window
|---------------------------------------|    
|\begin{abstract}                       |
|This is a bla like of text that will wr|ap here                            
|can you see the wrap                   |
|\end{abstract}                         |
|                                       |
|---------------------------------------|
```

The result is the following, which contains an undesirable `\t` in the next line

```
 *Inside of window                        *Outside of window
|---------------------------------------|    
|\begin{abstract}                       |
|This is a bla like of text that will   |
|    wrap here can you see the wrap     |
|\end{abstract}                         |
|                                       |
|---------------------------------------|
```

But, my goal is to have the result like the following, without the undesirable `\t` in the next line.

```
 *Inside of window                        *Outside of window
|---------------------------------------|    
|\begin{abstract}                       |
|This is a bla like of text that will   |
|wrap here can you see the wrap         |
|\end{abstract}                         |
|                                       |
|---------------------------------------|
```

I tried adding `set breakindent` to my `.vimrc` but it didn't work. Currently these are the lines I use regarding wrapping.

```
set wrap                                    " Wrap                                 
set textwidth=79                            " Default Text Width
```

Answer (score 0):

The indentation for Latex is determined by the `GetTeXIndent()` function (which can be found out via `:setlocal indentexpr?`). The corresponding script in `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/tex.vim` has documentation in its header. It mentions (among others) a config setting that affects the indentation of environments.

```
" * g:tex_noindent_env
"
"   A list of environment names. separated with '\|', where no indentation is
"   required. The default is 'document\|verbatim'.
```

If you add the `\begin{...}` item there (by putting the configuration into your `~/.vimrc`), no additional indent will happen:

```
let g:tex_noindent_env .= '\|begin'
```

<sup>Caveat: I know very little about Latex syntax; this may have unwanted side effects to formatting elsewhere. Read the entire indent documentation to understand your options for tweaking it.</sup>

Comment: I got this error when trying this solution. `E121: Undefined variable: g:tex_noindent_env`

Comment: Yes, because it appends to the default configuration; the answer assumed you're already editing a latex document. The indent script needs to be `:source`d first, or you duplicate the entire config value into your vimrc.