# How can I make vim break lines only on whitespace?

Tags: vim, editor, word-wrap

I want vim to wrap long lines, but not split words in the middle. I found this post: [Word wrap in Gvim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744159/word-wrap-in-gvim)

but that does not work for me. I already have `l` in formatoptions and linebreak enabled.

```
:set formatoptions?
formatoptions=lnq
```

As you can see, it is still splitting words: https://i.stack.imgur.com/diLlh.png

After consulting the relevant help pages, I also tried setting `breakat` to `\s`, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you found out this is done using the [`'linebreak'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27linebreak%27) option (with `'wrap'` on).

> If on Vim will wrap long lines at a character in `'breakat'` rather than at the last character that fits on the screen.

And since `'breakat'` by default contains Space and Tab and some punctuation characters, this should break lines as expected (not in the middle of a word). I suggest resetting `'breakat'` to the Vim default in case it has been changed by a plugin or a mapping.

Oh, and don't set `'list'`, these features don't mix.

All together now:

```
:set nolist wrap linebreak breakat&vim
```

Comment: So I have to choose between visible tabs and not breaking words for soft line wraps? That's very unusual and frustrating.

Comment: @Daniel Don't complain to me! This has actually been on the to-do list for a long time (`:h todo`). Until somebody takes the time to implement it, we won't have this feature, I'm afraid.

Comment: For future visitors to this page: this is changed now, you can use list and linebreak together.

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether you are talking about *hard* linebreaks, where a newline character is actually inserted into the text, or a *soft* linebreak, which only affects how the text is displayed on the screen.
I suspect that you are referring to the latter.

If that is correct, then you want to `:set list` and probably add `set list` to your vimrc.

Besides, wrapping the display,just the display, not the actual text at word boundaries, `list` also causes Vim to display various "invisible" characters, such as spaces, tabs, and (hard) newlines, according to the `listchars` variable (see `:help listchars` for more); if you want the soft line-wrapping at word boundaries but not invisible characters, you could presumably set the `listchars` to nothing.

I personally find that I sometimes want list enabled and sometimes not. `:set nolist` turns it off and `:set list!` toggles it. And just for completeness, `:set list?` tells you whether is is currently enabled or not. Those are all standard Vim conventions.

And if that's too much typing, you could set up a custom key mapping in your .vimrc, but that's another question.

Comment: I actually have list set already: `set listchars=tab:>-,trail:-`.

Whenever I `:set nolist`, the line wrap is no longer in the middle of the word, which puzzles me. The previous answer mentioned that the two are not compatible but I don't understand why.

Comment: Oh, right, my bad, sorry: word boundaries are ignored for the purposes of wrapping the display if `list` is *en*abled. I don't understand it either.